# What is the max timeout limit for Graph Authentication using Bot Framework and how do I set it?

Tags: oauth-2.0, botframework, microsoft-graph-api, azure-bot-service

I'm authenticating users through Microsoft Graph using the following code:

```
AddDialog(new OAuthPrompt(
    nameof(OAuthPrompt),
    new OAuthPromptSettings
    {
        ConnectionName = ConnectionName,
        Text = " Welcome! Please Sign In.",
        Title = "Sign In",
        Timeout = 999999999, // I don't want it to timeout
    })
);
```

Some of our users pressed the sign in button 30 minutes after it appeared, and they were told the token expired. How long is the max limit and how can I increase it?

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot answer the question about the settings in place, I will certainly recommend that you do not want the OAuth prompt to never expire.

The Bot Service will eventually return an access token from the configured authority (tenant). The Microsoft Identity Platform (Azure AD) provides [policies for token lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes), which may be appropriate.

In my experience, the user needs to login via OAuth and then tokens are re-acquired silently. Obviously, there are circumstances that will invalidate a refresh token, but for the most part the users happily interact with the bot without additional logins.

Comment: OAuthPromptSettings.Timeout is NOT the token expiration. It’s how long the OAuthPrompt will wait for user authentication - if user sees the login screen but doesn’t sign in within the timeout, next message from the user will trigger an auth failure.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a cap on the timeout of the OAuth CARD/PROMPT (not token), but the default is set to 900,000 ms (15 min in the SDK).

I agree with the other answer in that changing this is not recommended. Mainly, if you have an 'always on' prompt card, a user who has progressed in dialog with the bot and then goes back up and clicks the card once more has disrupted your dialog flow, a disruption you're going to have to account for in code.

That being said, the comments around the OAuthPromptSettings are as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the number of milliseconds the prompt waits for the user to authenticate.
/// Default is 900,000 (15 minutes).
/// </summary>
/// <value>The number of milliseconds the prompt waits for the user to authenticate.</value>

public int? Timeout { get; set; }
```